# sorting structures with name not working in C

Tags: c, sorting, structure

```
for(int i=0;i<numberOfStudents;i++){
        for(int j=i+1;j<numberOfStudents;j++){
            if (strcmp(newStudent[i].name,newStudent[j].name)>0){

                temp1=newStudent[i];
                newStudent[i]=newStudent[j];
                newStudent[j]=temp1;


            }


        }
    }
```

when i try to run this code every thing goes fine but newStudent reamain same unaltered or unsorted.

where `struct Student* newStudent = retrieve(filename, numberOfStudents);`

also retrive function definition is

```
struct Student* retrieve(const char* filename, int numberOfStudents) {

    static struct Student temp[25];
    FILE* fp;
    fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    if(fp==NULL){
        printf("error occured while reading from the file\n");
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfStudents; i++) {
        fread(&temp[i], sizeof(struct Student), 1, fp);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return temp;
}
```

i cant find mistake code. Program shows no error only problem is that output is not sorted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your swap in the innner loop is wrong. You overwrite `newStudent[i]` with its original value instead of swapping. It should look like:

```
            temp1=newStudent[i];
            newStudent[i]=newStudent[j];
            newStudent[j]=temp1;
```

Comment: i cant belive i did that silly mistake ,though checked that more than 20 times before posting  it here

Comment: Learn to use a debugger. Single stepping through this code would have shown you the problem immediately.